# AtomicReference Usage

Tags: java, multithreading, compare-and-swap

Say you have the following class

```
public class AccessStatistics {
  private final int noPages, noErrors;
  public AccessStatistics(int noPages, int noErrors) {
    this.noPages = noPages;
    this.noErrors = noErrors;
  }
  public int getNoPages() { return noPages; }
  public int getNoErrors() { return noErrors; }
}
```

and you execute the following code

```
private AtomicReference<AccessStatistics> stats =
  new AtomicReference<AccessStatistics>(new AccessStatistics(0, 0));

public void incrementPageCount(boolean wasError) {
  AccessStatistics prev, newValue;
  do {
    prev = stats.get();
    int noPages = prev.getNoPages() + 1;
    int noErrors = prev.getNoErrors;
    if (wasError) {
      noErrors++;
    }
    newValue = new AccessStatistics(noPages, noErrors);
  } while (!stats.compareAndSet(prev, newValue));
}
```

In the last two lines

```
newValue = new AccessStatistics(noPages, noErrors);
while (!stats.compareAndSet(prev, newValue))
```

Does it means the new created AccessStatistics instance has same reference as the current AccessStatistics instance. how could it be ? Can Anyone explain it . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stats.compareAndSet(prev, newValue)` will fail and return false if the current reference held by `stats` is not `prev`.

Typically, in a multi-threaded environment, it is very possible that between `prev = stats.get();` and `stats.compareAndSet(prev, newValue);` another thread would have modified the reference held by `stats`.

`stats.compareAndSet(prev, newValue);` really says:

- if `stats` still holds a reference to `prev`, as it was 5 lines before, update it to hold a reference to `newValue`
- if however another thread has already changed the reference held by `stats` since I last checked 5 lines ago, discard my calculation and loop to recalculate a new `newValue`.

Answer (score 0):

The newly created object is, well, new. After the line that it is created, the only thing that refers to it is `newValue`. Nothing else could -- how could it? The `compareAndSet()` only sets if nothing else has in the meantime set it to some third value, besides the old one you know about `prev` and the new one you made `newValue`.